# How to insert and get user specific data while using firebase auth and mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, firebase

I am currently using Firebase for auth and mongodb for storing data, everything works good.

I have only single admin user which can view and store data, Now i want to add another admin user but problem is that all data is shown to that user also, how to make it specific so only user who inserted the data can see it?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/

Comment: couldn't understand thanks anyways